# What is "Playstyle"?

Tags: thief

I just completed the first chapter, and was greeted with a screen similar to this, declaring my playstyle to have been that of an "opportunist":

[image: Screenshot with some statistics]

<sub><sup>The screenshot is actually from the statistics page in the menu, taken later, but it's the same chart)</sup></sub>

What the heck is this?

Specifically, what things contribute to each statistic? Predator sounds like it's combat related, and it outright says opportunist is related to 'using the environment', but it's all quite vague. And I don't understand why my Ghost rating is so low, given that I was never seen the whole time.

Also, more importantly, what does this do? Is there an effect on gameplay, similar to Dishonored's Chaos, or maybe a change to the ending, or is it all just fluff to tell me how I'm doing?

Comment: Infographics...

Comment: My guess: *Predator* is when you attack people, either knocking them out or killing them. *Ghost* might be when you make an effort to erase your presence, leaving everything as it originally was, like closing doors that were originally closed, never attacking people, and never being detected. *Opportunist* may be when you distract people by making sounds, or kick people down a balcony or something. It's just a guess though; I haven't played the game yet, so take my comment with a lot of salt.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The final play-style that you are awarded at the end of a level is dependent on the type of actions that you take while playing it. For each of these actions you earn points in one of the three categories, "Ghost", "Opportunist" and "Predator". The pie chart at the end shows the percentages of the points you earned in each category, and you are rated based on which category had a larger percentage.

### Ghost

You get points toward Ghost if you make it through the level without being detected, and without killing or performing knockouts . To get 100% you must also leave things more or less how you found them, no putting out lights, etc. Leaving doors open does not directly count against you. However if a NPC sees it opening or finds a door open that shouldn't be it might alert them, resulting in Opportunist points.

[image]

### Opportunist

Each light that you extinguish gives you a small amount of points toward Opportunist.
[image]

[Raising suspicions or being detected](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158738/what-does-it-mean-to-be-detected-or-raise-suspicion-in-thief/158739#158739) with give you a moderate amount of Opportunist points.

[image][image]

### Predator

Knocking out citizens will earn a large number of points towards Predator.

[image]

Killing guards or civilians will get you a very large number of points toward Predator.
[image]
[image]

### Hybrid actions

Knocking out guards will give you a moderate amount of both Opportunist and Predator points.
[image]

---

### Strategies for obtaining your desired play-style rating:

### Ghost

- Remain undetected
- No kills
- Very few if any knockouts
- Only extinguish lights when you feel it is absolutely necessary

### Opportunist

- Don't worry about raising suspicion, but try to not be detected so you can avoid combat and potential killing
- Extinguish lights as much as you want
- No kills
- Use knockouts sparingly

### Predator

- Kill, and knockout indiscriminately until your heart is content.

---

### Testing Methodology

The above conclusions are based on experiments I performed by running *Chapter 1* a number of times while doing slightly different things. I first did a 100% Ghost run to establish a baseline. Each run after that I did almost the same thing but performed a certain kind of task once (extinguish a light, knockout a guard, kill a guard, etc). I took roughly the same path every time but there were variations, it is possible that what I did or didn't do (more/less stealth actions, etc) may have had a small influence on the final percentages but that variance should not be large. From what I have observed, it should not affect the results; you don't really seem to earn Ghost points, you instead start with 100% Ghost and loose Ghost percent by gaining percentage in the other categories.  All tests were performed on "Rogue" difficulty to make things quick and more fool-proof, I don't know if difficulty level can influence the points awarded.

Comment: I'd immagine that indirect kills/environmental kills would count into opportunist (if those are possible; can't say for sure).

Comment: Nice answer! Kudos for doing your own research. :)

Comment: I've edited the embedded images to use StackExchange's imgur service instead, as the site the previous images were hosted at was pay-per-click and caused pornographic pop-ups.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks, didn't realize there were porn popups there... the hazards of using AdBlock I guess. That must be why they make you select "Adult" or "Family Safe" when uploading... I marked them as "Family Safe" so that's really irritating if they were showing inappropriate ads. As far as I am aware they don't have a PPC program, at least I wasn't getting paid.

Comment: for clarity: can you define "raising suspicion"? (i.e. is it the yellow eye; white eye with a single red dot etc.?).

Comment: @horatio I just posted a new question [explaining the different alertness levels](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158738/what-does-it-mean-to-be-detected-or-raise-suspicion-in-thief/158739#158739) and what they trigger.

Answer (score -1):

the prima website pretty much says ghost j achieved by leaving the environment untouched. that means no knockouts, kills, blowing out candles or dousing fires.

you can however use throwable objects to distract guards.

Comment: You can put out candles and turn out lights and still get Ghost, I've done it. There may be a limit to the number you can douse that I am not aware of. If there is a limit it seems to be reasonably high, I usually put out lights if guards are around and still get Ghost.

Comment: Guessing this is the article @keith is citing - http://www.primagames.com/games/thief/feature/thief-choose-your-style. It does seem to indicate extinguishing flames could effect your playstyle rating. Perhaps it matters whether you extinguish lights that guards can see, which could cause them to become more suspicious?

Comment: @raveturned Since it is represented as a pie chart at the end of a level I'm guessing things like putting out lights might count toward opportunist. Your final rating is probably just a matter of what type of action you use the most (and thus it shows up as the largest part of the pie). Like I said if you are strategic about what lights you extinguish and don't alert or attack anyone you will probably end up with Ghost as your dominate style.

Answer (score -1):

i ran the same tests with same to similar results. There was no variation in path taken. It does seem that picking pockets give little to or nithing as far as picking 4 there was no change in outcome. raising suspicion to 4 increased it by an 1/8 for the pie chart. Raised 3 guards to level one dot. Was on rogue as well. It would seem that you can distract guards but use it sparingly same with knockouts and turning lights out. I would assume as in not tested if you turn lights out and turn them back on before someone notices would be the same as closing doors. Not sure if disarming traps count against ghost style either safe be is that it probably would but it'd be nice to get a definite answer.