# What's the disadvantage of not completing bonus objectives?

Tags: thief

The first mission in Thief has a bonus objective "headshot 10 threats", but as a veteran Thief player killing random guards is completely unacceptable. Will I miss anything important by not completing this bonus objective?

Comment: Have you tried to complete one to see what you can get?

Comment: I believe you will get different bonus objectives depending on your [play style](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157746/what-is-playstyle), if you play in a stealthy manor you should start seeing stealthier bonus goals rather than aggressive ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get gold for completing bonus mission objectives.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I assumed. Still sucks that you get bonuses for acting very un-thief-ish.

Comment: There are different challenges each mission that encourages different styles of play. If you are ghosting, then you should be able to get the 'remain undetected' challenge. Or you can try to get the 'loot everything' challenge without being seen or knocking out anyone...